# Using Ctrl+V to paste unformatted text by default in OpenOffice.org's Calc

Tags: openoffice, paste

Is there a way to change the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> command in OpenOffice.org Calc to paste unformatted text?

There is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which puts up a dialog. But, that is too much work. I just want to change the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

**Steps to make CTRL+V to trigger 'Paste Unformatted Text'**:

**1. Create macro:**

- go in 'Tools > Macro > Record Macro'.
- A small box with a button 'Stop recording' button appears
- Place the mouse in one cell
- go in 'Edit > Paste Special > Unformatted text'
- press 'Stop recording' and
- save the macro with a name like 'PasteUnformatted'

**2. Trigger macro on CTRL+V:**

- Go to Tools > Customize > Keyboard (see screenshot below)
- Find the `Category` list *(bottom left - may need to scroll)*
- Select 'OpenOffice Macros > user > Standard > Module1'
- find your 'PasteUnformatted' macro
- Select CTRL+V in the 'Shortcut keys list'
- Click 'Modify' then 'OK'

[image: Tools > Customize > Keyboard with Macro and CTRL+V selected (mac)]

Comment: The other (accepted) answer may have been "right", but it isn't useful.  Thank you for saving me from formatted pasting with this simple explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just switch the assigned keys from Paste to Paste Unformatted, and from Paste Unformatted to Paste. I've done this in version 6.4. I haven't tested the idea in Calc or any other module.

What you want to do is change the keystrokes that are associated with the “Paste Unformatted” and “Paste” commands. You do this using the Keyboard Customization tool.

Start by choosing Tools –> Customize. When the dialog box appears, select the “Keyboard” tab.  A dialog box containing 4 panels and some control buttons appears.  The top panel contains a list of every key the system allows modifying along with the command that key performs. 
For example, pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> starts a formula expression;
<kbd>F11</kbd> invokes the styles panel.

[image: Keyboard Customization Dialog Box]

In the **Category** panel, lower left corner, scroll down and highlight the **Edit** Category.

In the **Function** Panel, scroll down, and highlight **Paste**. The **Keys** panel displays "Ctrl+Shift+V". Highlight that keystroke and click the **Delete** button (upper right). Leave this Function unassigned for the moment.

Now highlight the **Paste Unformatted Text** item in the **Function** box. The Keys panel will display "Ctrl+V". Click **Delete** for this key. 
Now neither function has a keystroke associated with it.

To associate Ctrl+Shift+V with the **Paste Unformatted Text** Function, go to the Shortcut Keys panel and highlight the **Ctrl+Shift+V** option. Click the **Modify** button. "Ctrl+Shift+V" now appears in the **Keys** panel on the lower left.

Go back to the **Paste** option in the **Function** panel. Find "Ctrl+V" in the top **Shortcut Keys** panel, highlight it and press the **Modify** button on the right. "Ctrl+V" appears in the **Keys** panel on the lower left.

Click **OK**. Your two paste functions are now associated with the keystrokes in the way you want them.

Comment: Question: “How do I drive from New York to Boston?”  Answer: “Simple! Just drive from New York to Boston.”   Do you see the circularity?  The question asks “Is there a way to do this?” and your answer just says to do it, without saying ***how**.*

Comment: That's a fair criticism. Since the answer is too long for a comment, I'm adding a new answer. I've edited my original answer to clarify matters for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why complicate things? A simpler way to paste Unformated Text with Ccontrol V is simply to record a macro (paste icon in top icon menu) where you manually paste unformated text. Next go to Tools, Adjust and select category macro, your macto, and the control-v option.

Save

Everytime you now use ctrl-v your text is pasted unformated.

Answer (score 1):

Autohotkey!

```
^+v::
bak = %clipboard%
clipboard = %bak%
Send ^v
return
```

That would replace Control-Shift-V with an "unformatted" paste, globally.

If you wanted it OOo Calc only, you'd do something like:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class [something]
^v::
bak = %clipboard%
clipboard = %bak%
Send ^v
return
#IfWinActive
```

Where [something] is the window's Class name, which you could easily find out with AHK's bundled Window Spy. (This one would actually replace Control-V (^ means control, + means shift), but doing that systemwide is a bad idea)