# How to paste raw text?

Tags: windows-7, windows, clipboard

Windows copies and pastes Rich Text. I want it to copy and paste only raw text. Is there any way to change this behaviour globally?

Someone in [another thread](https://superuser.com/questions/73450/using-ctrlv-to-paste-unformatted-text-by-default-in-openoffice-orgs-calc) suggested to use AutoHotKey tho change this, but I don't think this will work with my current clipboard manager [YC3](http://www.intelexual.com/products/YC3/)

Comment: Well.. no global but I just press WIN+R and paste there, ctrl+a, ctrl+c, its raw. Other way to open a notepad and do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/).

Answer (score 6):

As Shiki suggested the following steps do the trick:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: For multiline, perform these steps between 1 and 2: `Win+R`, `notepad`, `enter`

Comment: @Axidos In Windows 7 is even easier: Win, note, enter

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method for quickly reformatting text would be to paste the rich text; copy-format (SHIFT+CTRL+C) from any of the raw text you may have, and then paste-format (SHIFT+CTRL+V) over the rich text. This works throughout Office, YMMV outside of that.

Also, [CTRL+ALT+V] is the keyboard shortcut for Special Paste which will allow you various paste options depending on the Office program; including pasting all of the text as unicode, RTF, unformatted, and HTML in Word. This is subject to the User Settings you have for pasting actions (these were set up when the copy of Office was initialized, i.e. "Paste text as original format/new style").

Comment: didn't work for me at all

Comment: If you use the YCX version of YC3, Format options are available. ("Ability to send only selected formats to clipboard")

Comment: @Jad I use format copy/paste constantly in Office and other areas in Windows; I am unsure what program it didn't for you at all in.

Comment: I tried to use your hotkeys to copy from Internet Explorer into Office. Internet Explorer didn't recognize that combination

Comment: Sorry for my aversion to *yet another taskbar solution*, but try [CTRL+ALT+V] for special paste; it will allow you to strip formatting, however, if you have a default style for the document (ie, Arial 10pt) it may apply based on your Office Settings (verified going from a copied table in IE to MS-Word '07).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the clipboard manager still uses the standard windows clipboard (I have yet to see one that doesn't, though I've never used YC3), the autohotkey solution should work as normal - if your clipboard manager is overriding the windows clipboard entirely and doesn't supply an API, no other application can grab its clipboard data, so unless YC3 implements raw text pasting you're a bit stuck on the direct automation front - though you could always use AutoHotKey to automate Shiki's method of pasting it into a text field that doesn't accept rich text, and then copying it back out again.

Answer (score 1):

For Office Word 2007 and newer versions, in the "Advanced Options", in the section "Cut, Copy and Paste", there are 4 dropboxes where you can set value to always keep the base text style when pasting, depending from where your copy comes from.

Answer (score 1):

In windows (mine is Win8) Try 
<kbd>Menu key</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd>

You can find <kbd>Menu key</kbd> in this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) article.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows 7. Did you use the combination in any specific application?

Answer (score 0):

Unearthing this question because it is a common enough question and most people still don't know how to do it.

#### Paste unformatted

- In many apps and web apps (including for instance Google Docs), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pastes without formatting, which is very convenient.
- This does not work within the Office Suite. Instead, you can as @msg said (e.g. in Word) use `paste special` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> — or <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> if you prefer old school shortcuts! — then selecting `Unformatted Unicode Text` (you can navigate the interface with the <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> then validate your choice with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Windows Clipboard History

With Windows 10, I found little need for a dedicated clipboard manager anymore because there is a built-in Clipboard History which works very well (for formatted text and images).

It first needs to be activated :

- Open Windows Settings by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>
- Go to `System` → `Clipboard`
- Under `Clipboard history`, switch the toggle button to ON.

Then you use it by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>: this displays your clipboard history; you can browse it with the arrow keys and pick the one you want to paste with <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, I did not find a way to paste *raw* data from my clipboard history and still have to use Notepad for this.