# How to Paste raw text from clipboard to Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, clipboard

I have some text I want to copy, for example from an office document, from a mail document or anything else, into the windows explorer (the browser) without formatting.

I have tried to paste the text using WIN-V or SHIFT-WIN-V, which does not work. Neither does [PureText](http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) seem to work (formatting still pasted).

So how can I paste some text into a Windows Explorer field with all formatting (e.g. enumeration) removed?

Comment: This link does not help

Comment: What operating system I know older versions of windows had a clipboard viewer.  windows 8 doesn't seem to have it any more.

Comment: @Alex, if you don't want to download a separate tool like PureText (http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/) you could do what one comment (and an answer) in the link says (and what I usually do in those situations too) .. `CTRL+C` (copy text), `WIN+R` (open the 'Run' prompt), `CTRL+V` (paste into Run prompt), `CTRL+A` (select all text you just pasted), `CTRL+C` (copy un-formatted/raw text), `ESC` (close Run prompt), then `CTRL+V` (paste) into the app you want ... it's obtuse but "quick" and doesn't require a "separate" program ..

Comment: @txtechhelp I have seen this suggestion, but it is way too complicated for what I am copying. In that case it is easier to just paste the text and remove the three characters left to the actual text (in case I am copy from an enumeration: `1. `).

Answer (score 0):

Same question here. Hope it is the answer you are looking for.

[How to paste raw text?](https://superuser.com/questions/201445/how-to-paste-raw-text)

**EDIT:**

PureText only removes rich formatting from text.  This includes the font face, font style (bold, italics, etc.), font color, paragraph styles (left/right/center aligned), margins, character spacing, bullets, subscript, superscript, tables, charts, pictures, embedded objects, etc.  However, it does not modify the actual text.  It will not remove or fix new-lines, carriage returns, tabs, or other white-space.  It will not fix word-wrap or clean up your paragraphs.  If you copy the source code of a web page to the clipboard, it is not going to remove all the HTML tags.  If you copy text from an actual web page (not the source of the page), it will remove the formatting.

PureText is basically equivalent to opening Notepad, doing a PASTE, followed by a SELECT-ALL, and then a COPY.  The benefit of PureText is performing all these actions with a single Hot-Key and having the result pasted into the current window automatically.

I found this answer here: http://www.stevemiller.net/puretext/

Comment: I have seen this page but it was of no help.It did not solve my issue.

Comment: I'm kinda newbie on this forum. Thanks for making a point. Edited.